# How to Reconnect Apps to a Different Listener in a SQL Server Distributed Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, distributed-availability-groups

I have created a SQL Server Distributed Availability Group (AG), which spans two underlying AGs, each of them deployed on a Windows Cluster at a different location. I have also created a Listener for each "local" AG. My applications connect to the Primary AG using its listener. However, if this AG goes down and I need to failover to the Secondary AG at the other location (which has its own listener), the applications do not automatically reconnect to this second AG since it has a different listener. Is there a way to configure the apps so that they reconnect to the Secondary AG if the first one goes down and failed over?

Thank you. J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference:

1. [Configure an Always On distributed availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=automatic)
2. [An overview of distributed SQL Server Always On Availability Groups](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-distributed-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups/) by Rajendra Gupta
3. [Setup and Implement SQL Server 2016 Always On Distributed Availability Groups](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5053/setup-and-implement-sql-server-2016-always-on-distributed-availability-groups/) by Edwin Sarmiento

Make sure the endpoints can communicate between the different availability groups in the distributed availability group. If one availability group is set to a specific network on the endpoint, the distributed availability group does not work properly. On each server that hosts a replica in the distributed availability group, set the listener to listen on all IP addresses (LISTENER_IP = ALL).

Then you create a distributed availability group with both listeners.
Example:

```
CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP [distributedag]  
   WITH (DISTRIBUTED)   
   AVAILABILITY GROUP ON  
      'ag1' WITH    
      (   
         LISTENER_URL = 'tcp://ag1-listener.contoso.com:5022',    
         AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT,   
         FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL,   
         SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC   
      ),   
      'ag2' WITH    
      (   
         LISTENER_URL = 'tcp://ag2-listener.contoso.com:5022',   
         AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT,   
         FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL,   
         SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC   
      );    
GO
```

It does not have a mechanism to support the automatic failover between multiple clusters. A distributed availability group supports only manual failover using the FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS parameter

You cannot configure a listener for the distributed availability group. In this case, your application cannot redirect connections to another cluster (primary) automatically. It requires an explicit configuration in the application connection string

Comment: Or you can reconfigure the listener on the other AG after you force failover or drop the distributed availability group (if the main AG is unavailable).